# couldn't building Kotlin project:Could not resolve all files for configuration

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am trying to use Kotlin for first time in Android Studio. I updated Android Studio, but when I tried to build the project, I received the error message 
posted below. I tried to solve it by following some answers, but they could not solve the issue.

I tried to solve this issue by adding the following line to dependencies:

```
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
```

but it could not solve it.

please have a look at build file, and please let me know how to solve

**build-error**:

```
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration 
':classpath'.
Cause 1: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.61.
```

**gradle project**:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.1'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**gradle app**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.pc_amr.snakegame_01.app"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

buildTypes {
   release {
       minifyEnabled false
       proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
   }
}

}

dependencies {
implementation project(':feature')
implementation project(':base')
}
```

**Update**:

```
after adding that line to gradle.app:
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
i received the following error:

Unable to find method 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.BaseVariantData.getOutputs()Ljava/util/List;'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:<ul><li>Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</li><li>The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)</li><li>Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.</li></ul>In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

please note that, 
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.1'
and kotlin version in Android Studio is:
    version 1.2.61
```

Comment: Do you have `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'` at the top of your app-level Gradle config?

Comment: @TheWanderer no i dont have this file..it was not auto generated. how can i have it

Comment: @TheWanderer i found that line already exists in gradle file . app folder

Comment: Can you post that Gradle file as well?

Comment: @TheWanderer please have a look again at the ques. i add the gradle.app file

Comment: I don't see `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'`. It should be on the second line.

Comment: @TheWanderer please have a look at the update section i added iin the question

Comment: Fix your Kotlin version.

Comment: @TheWanderer i set to 1.2.62  but the problem still persists

Comment: The latest version is 1.2.61.

Comment: @TheWanderer ja..i mean 1.2.61...thats the current on i have ..but still the problem exists

Comment: Then click the `Re-download dependencies and sync project` link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed answering the question by setting the kotlin verion to:

```
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.60'
```

Comment: Where?  What does this line mean?

Answer (score 2):

Add this on top of your build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

and set `ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.61'` in project gradle

Comment: Why would an outdated version of Kotlin fix this?

Comment: would you please clarify..what do you mean by apply it on the top of build.gradle app??

Comment: do you see a build.gradle which is inside app directory?

Comment: yes..i found it, the line apply plugin: 'kotlin-android' is already there..the problem still exists

Comment: please post the text inside this build.gradle which is inside app directory

Comment: please have a look again at the ques. i add the gradle.app file

Comment: add the above line in answer in gradle.app

Comment: please have a look the update section i added to the question