# Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 15 |Compose Build error: Could not find androidx.compose:compose-compiler:1.0.0-beta06 |

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

as the title suggests I can't understand what the problem is when I try to deploy on the device.

The deployment fails when I try to add kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.0.0-beta06' to the gradle
and the error message is "Could not resolve all files for configuration ': app: kotlin-extension'. Could not find androidx.compose: compose-compiler: 1.0.0-beta06."

What I'm trying to do is add a piece of code written in compose starting from an existing project, and I'm following this guide https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis

I paste my gradle below:

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.findProperty("android.compileSdkVersion") as Integer
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId findProperty("android.applicationId")
        targetSdkVersion findProperty("android.targetSdkVersion") as Integer
        minSdkVersion findProperty("android.minSdkVersion") as Integer
        versionCode findProperty("android.minSdkVersion") as Integer
        versionName findProperty("android.versionName")
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
        // Enables Jetpack Compose for this module
        compose true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.0.0-beta06'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompat_version"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$ktx_version"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:$legacy_version"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$constraint_layout_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$recyclerview_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$material_version"

    // Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:$moshi_version"

    // Navigation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigation_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigation_version"
    // Compose
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$navigation_compose_version"
    // Material Design
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    // Tooling support (Previews, etc.)
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    // Foundation (Border, Background, Box, Image, Scroll, shapes, animations, etc.)
    implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$compose_version"
    // Material design icons
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version"
    // Integration with activitie
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha07"
    // Integration with ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:1.0.0-alpha04"
    // Integration with observable
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-rxjava2:$compose_version"

    // Coroutines
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:$coroutine_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutine_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutine_version"

    // Room
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"

    // Work Manager
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version"

    // Timber
    implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:$timber_version"

    // Glide
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

I'm using last version at moment I'm writing:

```
android.targetSdkVersion=30
android.minSdkVersion=28
android.versionCode=1
android.versionName=1.0.0
# gradle.properties
kotlin_version=1.4.30
gradle_version=4.1.1
ktlint_version=9.2.1
safe_args_version=1.0.0
appcompat_version=1.2.0
ktx_version=1.3.2
legacy_version=1.0.0
constraint_layout_version=2.0.4
lifecycle_version=2.3.1
recyclerview_version=1.2.0
material_version=1.3.0
retrofit_version=2.9.0
moshi_version=1.9.2
navigation_version=2.3.5
navigation_compose_version=1.0.0-alpha10
compose_version=1.0.0-beta06
coroutine_version=1.4.2
room_version=2.3.0
work_version=2.5.0
timber_version=4.7.1
glide_version=4.12.0
```

I'm following the official setup but not seem woking

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup

[image]

Comment: Okay sorry my answer didn't help, so I deleted it :)

Comment: It might be because the package is not hosted anywhere. It looks like they should upload the package to maven repository. If you try to visit those 2 links in your screenshot above "Required by:", they don't work for me.

Comment: yeah that's right, they don't even work for me to be honest. maybe something is missing in the project build.gradle but I don't know what and the documentation wouldn't seem to say much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem.

Inside build.gradle (project level) I was using:

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradle_version"
```

So creating new Compose project I found how to fix the problem. In particular:

## build.gradle (project level) is like:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha15"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.32"
        classpath "org.jlleitschuh.gradle:ktlint-gradle:$ktlint_version"
        classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.5")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

## build.gradle (app level) is like:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.findProperty("android.compileSdkVersion") as Integer
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId findProperty("android.applicationId")
        targetSdkVersion findProperty("android.targetSdkVersion") as Integer
        minSdkVersion findProperty("android.minSdkVersion") as Integer
        versionCode findProperty("android.minSdkVersion") as Integer
        versionName findProperty("android.versionName")
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        useIR = true
    }
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
        kotlinCompilerVersion '1.4.32'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompat_version"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$ktx_version"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:$legacy_version"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$constraint_layout_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$recyclerview_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$material_version"

    // Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:$moshi_version"

    // Navigation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigation_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigation_version"
    // Compose
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$navigation_compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha07'

    // Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_version"

    // Coroutines
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:$coroutine_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutine_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutine_version"

    // Room
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"

    // Work Manager
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version"

    // Timber
    implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:$timber_version"

    // Glide
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

and Upgrade JDK to 11 using embedded JDK

[image]

and at last upgrade gradle to 7.0.0

[image]

P.S.

here gradle.properties:

```
# Common Android settings
android.compileSdkVersion=30
android.applicationId=com.composetest.application
android.targetSdkVersion=30
android.minSdkVersion=28
android.versionCode=1
android.versionName=1.0.0
# gradle.properties
kotlin_version=1.4.32
gradle_version=4.1.1
ktlint_version=9.2.1
safe_args_version=1.0.0
appcompat_version=1.3.0-beta01
ktx_version=1.3.2
legacy_version=1.0.0
constraint_layout_version=2.0.4
lifecycle_version=2.3.1
recyclerview_version=1.2.0
material_version=1.3.0
retrofit_version=2.9.0
moshi_version=1.9.2
navigation_version=2.3.5
navigation_compose_version=1.0.0-alpha10
compose_version=1.0.0-beta06
coroutine_version=1.4.2
room_version=2.3.0
work_version=2.5.0
timber_version=4.7.1
glide_version=4.12.0
fragment_version = 1.3.3
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue yesterday. What I did was adding compiler in the compose option.

```
composeOptions {

       kotlinCompilerVersion "1.4.32"
       kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.0.0-beta06"
   }
```

Found somewhat similar issue to yours in stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64377577/gradle-cannot-find-android-compose-compiler). You may need to upgrade your gradle version.

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52236029/couldnt-building-kotlin-projectcould-not-resolve-all-files-for-configuration), (if you haven't already) set ext.kotlin_version = .....   in the project gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.32"
    ext {  ....   }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google() 
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            google()
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the support. But unfortunately something will be missing because it keeps giving me the same error